# R: Passing information into renderPlot from reactive function

Tags: r, shiny

all. I am very new to shiny and R but am trying to learn my way through it.

I could use your help learning how to pass information from the reactive function into renderPlot. I have successfully used my reactive function to build a data frame but, when I try and plot it in renderPlot using ggplot, the data is not available.

In renderPlot, I am getting the error that 'the object "product" does not exist'. Any thoughts?

```
server <- function(input, output) 
{
reactive_data <- reactive({

                finalData <- data.frame(ITEM_DESC=as.character(), revenue=double(), product=character())

                for (p in input$product_selection){

                    tempData <- orderData %>%
                        filter(grepl(p, ITM_DESC)) %>%
                        select(ITM_DESC, revenue) %>%
                        group_by(ITM_DESC) %>%
                        summarize(rev=sum(revenue))

                    tempData <- tempData %>% mutate(product = p)

                    if (dim(finalData)[1] == 0) {
                        finalData <- tempData
                    }
                    else{
                        finalData <- bind_rows(finalData, tempData)
                    }
                }

            })

# Render Plot
output$shinyOrders <- renderPlot(
                        ggplot(reactive_data()) +
                        geom_col(aes_string(x="product", y="rev")) +
                        theme_bw(18) +
                        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
                        )
}

# ---- Run App ----

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `for` loops do not return anything. You need to return `finalData` explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops do not return anything. Observe:

```r
(for (i in 1:3) i <- i+1)
# NULL
i
# [1] 4
```

I think that makes your solution (untested):

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  reactive_data <- reactive({

    finalData <- data.frame(ITEM_DESC=as.character(), revenue=double(), product=character())

    for (p in input$product_selection){

      tempData <- orderData %>%
        filter(grepl(p, ITM_DESC)) %>%
        select(ITM_DESC, revenue) %>%
        group_by(ITM_DESC) %>%
        summarize(rev=sum(revenue))

      tempData <- tempData %>% mutate(product = p)

      if (dim(finalData)[1] == 0) {
        finalData <- tempData
      }
      else{
        finalData <- bind_rows(finalData, tempData)
      }
    }

    return(finalData) # <--------- you need this

  })

  # Render Plot
  output$shinyOrders <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(reactive_data()) +
      geom_col(aes_string(x="product", y="rev")) +
      theme_bw(18) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  )
}

# ---- Run App ----

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had made the assumption that anything done in the reactive scope was available. In what other situations would I need to have a return value? Or maybe, in what situations do you not need a return value?

Comment: If you do not explicitly use `return(x)` (or just `x`) in a reactive block, then you are relying on *implicit* returns. This is often okay but will severely bite you when you aren't prepared. The implicit return value is the last value used. If you do something like `mtcars[,2] <- mtcars[,2]+1`, you might think it will return a modified frame, but it will not ... the RHS of that assignment is just a vector (6+1,6+1,4+1,...), so the return value from that is the vector (column 2). If you needed that to return the whole frame, then you'd need to follow that with at least `mtcars` (for the whole)

Comment: In a different view, in a *functional paradigm*, everything inside the function is in its own environment/namespace. With scope, when a variable is referenced inside a function that does not exist there, R will look outside of the function (in successive envs) until it finds the variable (or fails), and many consider this to be dangerous (unreproducible). On the flip side, things created in the function exist only in that function and "expire" when the function returns. The only way to preserve values from inside is to `return` them (or other drastic/bad measures).

Comment: Thanks for all the detail! This all makes sense.